# Why does this buffer apply a DC voltage through a high pass filter to the output?

Tags: audio, buffer

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVV7wC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What is the purpose of C3 and R5 in series between +9v and the Output? The only thing I could think of is that it supplies additional current, but I don't understand how it could supply current though a capacitor.

This circuit is the buffer that was in Jerry Garcia's "Tiger" guitar. I used [this](https://images.app.goo.gl/BLqpRnnUT4vixciy6) perfboard layout as a reference.

Comment: Are those really 1 milliohm resistors, or did you mean 1M ohm (1 million ohm) resistors?

Comment: I get that this is just an example circuit, but why on earth would you use a milliohm for R2 and R3?

Comment: In any case, this looks like it's to allow some of the output signal to feed back into the input. For what reason I couldn't tell you. (this effect wouldn't work if V1 is an ideal voltage source, though)

Comment: More likely for some kind of filter and attenuation of the output.  Normally it would go to ground, but with the capacitor in there it doesn't matter if it goes to ground or V+.

Comment: I don't think you have translated the schematic correctly. The 22nF goes directly from power to ground as decoupling. The 10K resistor goes directly from the output to ground to ensure there is not DC on the output.

Comment: The engineer must have been downwind.

Comment: Kevin White, you are correct. I misread the stripboard layout. And to everyone asking about R2 and R3 I made a typing mistake. They were meant to be in mega-ohms.

Comment: Would it be preferable if I deleted this post of if I posted an answer to my own question clarifying I had made a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the correct optional arrangements.

[image]

[REF](https://music-electronics-forum.com/showthread.php?t=17122)